# Document download counter? Using Node.js, express, mongo, mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, analytics

I'm working on a medium size company's intranet. The website is hosted on-site, and will have many links to documents hosted on the same server.
Does anybody know what's the best/easiest way to keep count of downloads of each document?
Website developed using Node.js, express, mongo, mongoose.

Comment: We don't tend to answer "best tool" questions.  Have you tried any analytics tool?  If you have tried one and are having trouble integrating, please explain what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: His isn’t a best tool question, the question is recommending an approach

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks for your reply. I have looked into some analytic tool, but it seemed rather complicated to integrate for my purpose. I may be wrong, and maybe that'd be the only way to keep an "accessed/downloaded' count. So I guess my question would be if there's a simpler approach or built-in method, perhaps Windows/IIS logs? But I haven't been able to find anything like that. Im using Windows Server 2012 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing to do would be to just have a mongo document holding the metadata about each file, and then increment the “downloads” field of that every time it’s downloaded.

Slightly harder but probably more useful would be to log info about each download either in its own mongo record or to the system logs.  In that case you’re going to capture things like which user, when, etc, which you’d then count to get the total, but you could also do things like see which user did it or more complex things like which department is doing the most downloading, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The system log was my first instinct, but I couldn't find this information, do you know where would it be stored?

Comment: Depends on how you run your app. What I meant by system log was the stdout of the Node app, and your app would explicitly log the info to stdout.  Where that goes depends on your system and configuration but ideally you’re doing some kind of log aggregation. If using ELK stack (which I recommend), it’s pretty easy to later query Elastic for the event info you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of all that are using your file, that you can do is that keep a logger as middleware in express as a result you will be a find who all have access to file by searching the log. **[morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan)** is a good logger which helps you this.